# Converting Pandas DataFrame OrderedSet column into list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, apply

I have a Pandas DataFrame, one column, is an `OrderedSet` like this:

df

```py
     OrderedSetCol
0    OrderedSet([1721754, 3622558, 2550234, 2344034, 8550040])
```

This is:

```
  from ordered_set import OrderedSet
```

I am just trying to convert this column into list:

```
df['OrderedSetCol_list'] = df['OrderedSetCol'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(str("\'" + x.replace('OrderedSet(','').replace(')','') + "\'")))
```

The code executes succesfully, but, my column type is still `str` and not `list`

```
type(df.loc[0]['OrderedSetCol_list'])

str
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My `OrderedSetCol` is also a string column as I am reading a file from a disk, which was originally saved from OrderedSet column.

Expected Output:

```
[1721754, 3622558, 2550234, 2344034, 8550040]
```

Comment: Can you please share your sample dataframe with `OrderedSetCol` with expected output.

Comment: done, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a `list` calling just like you would do with the `OrderedSet` itself:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'OrderedSetCol':[OrderedSet([1721754, 3622558, 2550234, 2344034, 8550040])]})
df.OrderedSetCol.apply(list)
```

Output:

```
[1721754, 3622558, 2550234, 2344034, 8550040]
```

---

If your data type string column:

```
df.OrderedSetCol.str.findall('\d+')
```